# What is the total kinetic energy per second of the particles accelerated by the LHC

Tags: particle-physics, energy, large-hadron-collider, accelerator-physics, protons

Related: how many protons per second can the LHC accelerate?

Comment: More on LHC: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3468/2451

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/what-would-happen-if-you-put-your-hand-in-front-of-the-7-tev-beam-at-lhc/3471#3471) from another question says:

> Each bunch of protons circulating in the LHC at full power will have about 120 billion protons of 14 TeV each, i.e. $1.6 \times 10^{24}$ eV which is about 250000 Joules.

Additionally, the comment below says that there can be up to 2808 bunches in the ring at a given time. Note also that the per proton energy should be 7 TeV/proton, not 14 TeV.

The circumference of the LHC is 27 km.  Dividing by the speed of light, you find that the particles take 90 μs to complete a trip around the ring.  Combining this with the numbers given in the linked answer, we can answer your questions:

> What is the total kinetic energy per second of the particles accelerated by the LHC?

The total kinetic energy per second (i.e. power) passing through a given slice of the beamline at full capacity is:

2808 * 125000 Joules / 90 μs $\approx$ 4 Terawatts

> Related: how many protons per second can the LHC accelerate?

The rate of protons passing a given point is:

2808 * 60 billion protons / 90 μs $\approx$ 10^18 protons/second

However, this isn't really "many protons per second can the LHC accelerate", since the LHC operates in cycles of filling up with protons, accelerating, and dumping/colliding.

Comment: Note that the accelerator does not *dissipate* that much power (the loss of kinetic energy proceeds only through Bremstraulung and collision plus there are other inefficiencies in the system), but that the load due to a large accelerator is enough that the local power company in Illinois needed to be informed ahead of time before FNAL fired up the Tevatron.

Comment: Note that the 4 Terawatts counts each particle about 11'000 times (the number of revolutions per second). You could not exploit this power: if you were to fully absorb the energy of the particles (e.g. at the beam dump), the machine would be empty after one revolution.